# Função em Python de coluna para uma lista

Tags: python, funções, lista

Preciso criar uma função que adiciona colunas de uma lista em outra lista na mesma ordem seguindo essa estrutura aqui (pode usar FOR).

```
def column_to_list(data, index):
    column_list = []
    # código entra aqui nesta parte
    return column_list
```

Como posso fazer isso? Ainda não aprendi direito a utilizar os argumentos em meu favor.

Um exemplo seria uma coluna Gênero, com diversas entradas de Masculino e Feminino. Preciso pegar estes resultados destas linhas e transformar em uma única lista.

output = ['M','F','F','M','F']

Comment: Opa, coloca em português, esse Stack Overflow é só nessa língua.

Comment: Desculpe, agora que percebi! Irei alterar!

Comment: Quando for [edit] aproveita para colocar exemplos de resultados que a função deverá retornar.

Comment: Ainda precisamos de mais detalhes. Por favor, crie essa lista que possui diversas entradas de masculino e feminino e a partir dela nos mostre como seria a chamada da função que retornaria a saída citada.

Comment: Como que é o formato da entrada? A saída já temos. Passa exemplos de entrada (os dados que você insere por parâmetro em data e index) que a gente te ajuda pra obter aquela saída.

Answer (score 1):

```
banco = [['Carlos', 'M'],
         ['Frenanda', 'F'],
         ['Gilberto', 'M']]

def column_to_list(data, index):
    column_list = []
        for pessoa in data:
            column_list.append(pessoa[index])
    return column_list

generos = column_to_list(banco, 1)
```

ñ testei, mas 99% de chace de funcionar